# the element inside the ScroolView is not visible

Tags: java, android

To display my elements, I added several Constraint Layout. And if you add an element inside the second one, it will not be visible. What could be the problem?

XML

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_border_layout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/vector_right_yellow_main"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/vector_left_yellow_main"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Купить\nмикронаушник"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:text="В 33 городах"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                    android:text="Выбрать свой ❯"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_blue"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Microgatgets - бренд микронаушников"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                    android:text="№1 в мире"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_blue"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Незаметно, безопасно, легально.\nСобственное производство и гарантия низких цен."
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_border_layout"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/earphone_capsule"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                        android:text="От 999 руб"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="112dp"
                        android:layout_height="47dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                        android:src="@drawable/change_earphones_text"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/background_student"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:text="Хиты продаж"/>



            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Image
[image]

The TextView is located at the bottom. It is added, highlighted, but it is not visible, even if you run the application. I tried adding padding or margin, changing the size of Scrollview and ConstraintLayout - it didn't help

Comment: app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
 where You Declare Your constraintLayout above ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code, Please remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from `constraintLayout2` and add `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` into `constraintLayout2` and remove `android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"` from `ConstraintLayout` that contains `TextView`

Comment: Appreciate me by upvoting the answer if this answer helps you. Thanks